# How do I show two images with different height/width ratios side by side with equal heights, in fluid div that covers percentage of window width?

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I'm not sure if I can do this, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201230/how-to-shrink-a-div-around-a-scaled-img) comes so close, I can't imagine it is impossible.

I'm aiming for a pure CSS/HTML solution.
I want two images with natively different heights to appear side by side with equal heights.
I want the left image to cover 60% of a div, the right image can have the remaining 40% (I know it will be less than 40% wide, but not its exact width).
The combo should appear in a div that covers 70% of the window width, regardless of the window size. [Example of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpAy7.jpg)
Both images should retain their aspect ratio. Above left drawing shows a browser window with the unscaled images, the second is where the div covers about 60% of the window width, with the images showing in equal heights, and regardless of the browser window width, these percentages should remain unaltered, as I tried to show in the third and fourth diagram.

I've tried numerous variations, but often the right image wraps under the left one if the window becomes too small, or the images only scale with window height, which is definitely not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bare-bones example of my solution, using an embedded stylesheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Stackoverflow Question</title>
    <style>
div {
   height: /*unfortunately cannot be a percentage*/ 200px;
   width: 70%;
}

img.leftimage {
   float: left;
   width: 60%;
   height: 100%;
}

img.rightimage {
   float: right;
   width: 40%;
   height: 100%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="droids.jpg" class="rightimage" />
        <img src="WinZip.png" class="leftimage" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMonkey14/ULy46/4/) is a fiddle using colors instead of images, and if it matters these are the images I used above - clearly different height/width ratios:

[image: Droids]
[image: WinZip]

Comment: That is close, but you gave the image on the right a 40% width. That deforms the image; if you swap the images for illustration's purpose, you will notice that the images are stretched or compressed, they did not keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: It is good enough to get me fiddling with the stuff; I guess next is to have height as a fixed ratio of the window width, [using padding as a percentage](http://jsfiddle.net/ks2jH/217/). This hopefully circumvents the ['cannot be percentage' comment](http://jsfiddle.net/ULy46/13/) you put in.

Comment: [MacOS:]Firefox fails. Opera fails. Chrome succeeds. Safari succeeds. iCab succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Kitting the beg borrow and steal together, I get this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Md2AN/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Stackoverflow Question</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .aspectwrapper {
            display: inline-block; /* shrink to fit */
            width: 40%; /* whatever percentage of window's width you like */
            position: relative; /* so .content can use position: absolute */
            }
            .aspectwrapper::after {
            padding-top: 40%; /* play with this to fit both images in one line */
            display: block;
            content: '';
            }
            .content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; /* follow the parent's edges */
            outline: thin dashed green; /* just so you can see the box */
            overflow: hidden;
            }
            .images {float: left;}
            img {width: auto;height: 100%;}        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="aspectwrapper">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="images">                                
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
          </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```